# Numerically compute derivative in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

So I have a MATLAB assignment where we need to compute the derivative of a function using

> d f(x)/dx = (f(x0+h) - f(x0-h))/2h

So I made this into a new function and want to pass in the function I want the derivative taken of.

I'm very new to MATLAB, so help would be greatly appreciated.  Here's what I got, trying to compute the derivative at `x = 0.6`:

```
%% Problem 2
syms x;
funct1 = @(x) (x^3)*exp(2*x)
x0     = 0.6;
der1   = FunDer(@funct1,x0);

%% The saved function in a separate file
function [ der ] = FunDer(@funct1,x0)
    % function to calculate derivative
    h   = 1e-5;
    x1  = x0+h;
    x2  = x0-h;
    der = (subs(@funct1,x,x1) - subs(@funct1,x,x2)) / (2*h);
end
```

Comment: In newer Matlab version the function does not need to go in a separate file per se.

Answer (score 1):

As you have used a anonymous function, you need not use *sym*. Check the below modified code:

```
%% Problem 2
% syms x;
funct1 = @(x) (x^3)*exp(2*x)
x0=0.6;
der1=FunDer(funct1,x0)

%%The saved function in a separate file
function [ der ] = FunDer(funct1,x0)
%function to calculate derivative
h=0.00001;
x1=x0+h;
x2=x0-h;
der = (funct1(x1)-funct1(x2))/(2*h);
end
```